# Load WMS service, the url is too long to get data

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

Load WMS service, the url is too long to get data

Load a WMS service, do not add "CQL_FILTER" parameter can request to the data, add "CQL_FILTER" parameter can not get, who can help me to analyze it? Thank you very much!

"http://192.168.8.254:8080/geoserver/workspaceTest/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&styles=&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&width=256&height=256&transparent=true&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image/png&layers=workspaceTest:accMV03&CQL_FILTER=WITHIN(GEOM, SRID = 3857; MULTIPOLYGON(((12255325.69509 3791918.95510, 12616926.21400 3762599.99411, 12646245.17499 3547594.28016, 12284644.65608 3547594.28016, 12255325.69509 3791918.95510))))"

Can post requests be used?

Answer (score 0):

I have published a WMS service by geosever, and there is no problem in loading json file or rasterlayer. Now I use the cql_filter of geoserver to search the data within the search range. If the cql_filter parameter is added into the url, the style content cannot be obtained.
I want to ask:
1. How does mapbox-ios use post to request WMS or vector data?
2. Why is it not possible to get style content when CQL_FILTER parameter is added to the url, while the browser can?

My url:

```
http://192.168.8.254:8080/geoserver/workspaceTest/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&styles=&bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&width=256&height=256&transparent=true&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image/png&layers=workspaceTest:accMV03&cql_filter=WITHIN(GEOM,SRID=3857;MULTIPOLYGON(((12255325.69509 3791918.95510, 12616926.21400 3762599.99411, 12646245.17499 3547594.28016, 12284644.65608 3547594.28016, 12255325.69509 3791918.95510))))
```

My log:

```
 [ERROR] {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 2/2/1=>2 for source mapbox-streets: unsupported URL
[ERROR] {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 3/6/3=>3 for source mapbox-streets: unsupported URL
```